# why is my code not working , volume of cylinder?

Tags: c

Someone please fix for me: volume of cylinder, but I am getting constant errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const float pi = 3.14;
    float r, h, vol;

    printf("Enter Radius Of the Cylinder.\n");
    scanf("%f", &r);

    printf("Enter Height of the Cylinder.\n");
    scanf("%f", h);

    vol = r * r * pi * h;

    printf("Volume Of Cylinder is %f", vol);
     
    return 0;
}
```

someone please fix for me !

Answer (score 2):

The bug is you do not pass the address of `h` in `scanf("%f", h)`. Use this instead:

```
    scanf("%f", &h);
```

Compiling with all warnings enabled would have reported this problem with a warning or an error message: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Note also these remarks:

- use a more accurate value for **π**: `const float pi = 3.14159265f;`
- check the return value of `scanf()`
- end your output with a newline

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const float pi = 3.14159265f;
    float r, h, vol;

    printf("Enter radius of the cylinder:\n");
    if (scanf("%f", &r) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Enter height of the cylinder:\n");
    if (scanf("%f", &h) != 1)
        return 1;

    vol = r * r * pi * h;

    printf("Volume of cylinder is %f\n", vol);
     
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RobbaN: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.